# How back to main ViewController (SWRevealViewController)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swrevealviewcontroller

I have implemented a Slide-Out Sidebar Menu using `SWRevealViewController` subclass and it works(on storyboard).

At first appear my main controller where i can choose some of `sw_front` controller from menu controller. The issue is that I don't get the back from `sw_front` controller to my main controller?(swift 4.0)